# How to include ft2build.h in SDL2 CMake project

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I want to compile a CMake project using SDL2 and SDL_ttf library.

I copied "SDL_ttf.c" & "SDL_ttf.h" into my src folder.
(**EDIT**: removed it, see comments)

I also added this to my `CMakeLists.txt`:
`include_directories(${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})`

freetype2 is also installed

but i get the error after calling make

```
src/SDL_ttf.c:28:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
28 | #include <ft2build.h>
```

How do i properly install SDL_ttf to my system?
(https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt)

**EDIT:**

my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_definitions(-std=c++17)

set(CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, "${CXX_FLAGS}")

project(SDL2Test)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} src)
include_directories(${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(Zokoban src/main.cpp src/game.cpp src/controller.cpp src/renderer.cpp src/hero.cpp src/level.cpp)
string(STRIP ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} SDL2_LIBRARIES)
target_link_libraries(Zokoban ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

**EDIT2:**

after sudo make install (SDL_ttf source) and removing the SDL-source files from my repo:

```
[ 57%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Zokoban.dir/src/renderer.cpp.o
/07_Capstone/Zokoban/src/renderer.cpp:9:10: fatal error: SDL_ttf.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <SDL_ttf.h>
```

**EDIT3**

On another machine (debian11) i couldn't even compile the SDL_ttf - source

```
19:46 $ 
✔ ~/ThirdParty/SDL_ttf/build [main|✚ 3…1] 
19:46 $ make
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"2.21.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"SDL2_ttf\ 2.21.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/issues\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DSDL_BUILD_MAJOR_VERSION=2 -DSDL_BUILD_MINOR_VERSION=21 -DSDL_BUILD_MICRO_VERSION=0 -DPACKAGE=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DVERSION=\"2.21.0\" -DTTF_USE_HARFBUZZ=1 -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -DALIGNOF_STRUCT_CHAR__=1 -I. -I..   -I../external/freetype/include -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY -DFT_PUBLIC_FUNCTION_ATTRIBUTE= -I../external/harfbuzz -I../external/harfbuzz/src -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFT_CONFIG_OPTION_USE_HARFBUZZ   -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -Wall -fvisibility=hidden  -DHAVE_OPENGL -MT libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.Tpo -c -o libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.lo `test -f 'SDL_ttf.c' || echo '../'`SDL_ttf.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"2.21.0\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"SDL2_ttf 2.21.0\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/issues\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DSDL_BUILD_MAJOR_VERSION=2 -DSDL_BUILD_MINOR_VERSION=21 -DSDL_BUILD_MICRO_VERSION=0 -DPACKAGE=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DVERSION=\"2.21.0\" -DTTF_USE_HARFBUZZ=1 -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -DALIGNOF_STRUCT_CHAR__=1 -I. -I.. -I../external/freetype/include -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY -DFT_PUBLIC_FUNCTION_ATTRIBUTE= -I../external/harfbuzz -I../external/harfbuzz/src -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFT_CONFIG_OPTION_USE_HARFBUZZ -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -DHAVE_OPENGL -MT libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.Tpo -c ../SDL_ttf.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.o
../SDL_ttf.c:28:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
   28 | #include <ft2build.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:1539: libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.lo] Error 1
```

.. although **ft2build.h** is obviously installed:

```
ls /usr/include/freetype2/
freetype  ft2build.h
```

**EDIT4:**

I downloaded from https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/releases "SDL2_ttf-2.20.0.tar.gz". And could `configure`, `make` and `sudo make install` SDL_ttf.

... but `make` my project is still not possible

```
18:03 $ make
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Zokoban.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Zokoban.dir/src/game.cpp.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Zokoban.dir/src/controller.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Zokoban.dir/src/renderer.cpp.o
/home/Zokoban/src/renderer.cpp:9:10: fatal error: SDL_ttf.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <SDL_ttf.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

When i tried it with the released sourcecode i get still the error.

```
~/learning/ThirdParty/SDL_ttf-release-2.20.0/build$ make
depbase=`echo showfont.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"2.20.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"SDL2_ttf\ 2.20.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/issues\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_STDIO_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DSDL_BUILD_MAJOR_VERSION=2 -DSDL_BUILD_MINOR_VERSION=20 -DSDL_BUILD_MICRO_VERSION=0 -DPACKAGE=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DVERSION=\"2.20.0\" -DTTF_USE_HARFBUZZ=1 -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -DALIGNOF_STRUCT_CHAR__=1 -I. -I..     -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -Wall -fvisibility=hidden  -DHAVE_OPENGL -MT showfont.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o showfont.o ../showfont.c &&\
mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"2.20.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"SDL2_ttf\ 2.20.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/issues\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_STDIO_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DSDL_BUILD_MAJOR_VERSION=2 -DSDL_BUILD_MINOR_VERSION=20 -DSDL_BUILD_MICRO_VERSION=0 -DPACKAGE=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DVERSION=\"2.20.0\" -DTTF_USE_HARFBUZZ=1 -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -DALIGNOF_STRUCT_CHAR__=1 -I. -I..   -I../external/freetype/include -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY -DFT_PUBLIC_FUNCTION_ATTRIBUTE= -I../external/harfbuzz -I../external/harfbuzz/src -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFT_CONFIG_OPTION_USE_HARFBUZZ   -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -Wall -fvisibility=hidden  -DHAVE_OPENGL -MT libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.Tpo -c -o libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.lo `test -f 'SDL_ttf.c' || echo '../'`SDL_ttf.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"2.20.0\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"SDL2_ttf 2.20.0\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/issues\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DHAVE_STDIO_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DSDL_BUILD_MAJOR_VERSION=2 -DSDL_BUILD_MINOR_VERSION=20 -DSDL_BUILD_MICRO_VERSION=0 -DPACKAGE=\"SDL2_ttf\" -DVERSION=\"2.20.0\" -DTTF_USE_HARFBUZZ=1 -DHAVE_CXX11=1 -DALIGNOF_STRUCT_CHAR__=1 -I. -I.. -I../external/freetype/include -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY -DFT_PUBLIC_FUNCTION_ATTRIBUTE= -I../external/harfbuzz -I../external/harfbuzz/src -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFT_CONFIG_OPTION_USE_HARFBUZZ -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2 -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -DHAVE_OPENGL -MT libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.Tpo -c ../SDL_ttf.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.o
../SDL_ttf.c:28:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
   28 | #include <ft2build.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:1536: libSDL2_ttf_la-SDL_ttf.lo] Error 1
```

My ideas run out :(

Comment: If your system doesn't have a SDL_ttf development package, then you need to build the actual library and install it, rather than copy a couple of source files.

Comment: By the way, you of course need to install the freetype2 development package, as that include the freetype2 library header files.

Comment: *I copied "SDL_ttf.c" & "SDL_ttf.h" into my src folder.* Very bad idea. The correct way is to install files where they are supposed to go, and then tell your project where those files are located. Copying stuff around is inefficient (are you going to copy those files multiple times if you use them in multiple projects) and contradicts the way tools like CMake are supposed to work.

Comment: How do I install SDL_ttf, see [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation) maybe. Those instructions are for SDL not SDL_ttf, but I imagine the processes are similar for both.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i installed all the freetype dev packages and it did not work thats why i tried to copy the SDL_ttf sources - files, maybe CMakeList.txt is wrong (see above)

Comment: Check out the SDL_ttf repository. `cd` to the local repository. `mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; make; sudo make install`. That should build the library and install it in `/usr/local`. After this you, hopefully all you need is `find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)` in your own `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: i forgot to 'sudo make install' ... ^^ . but th header <SDL_ttf.h> is still missing. see above - updated CMakeLists and Edit2